# How to change HiddenInput value of form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a url from the title of an object which is given by the user. I figured I could do this in the `clean_url` method of the form but it does not seem to work.

```
    def clean_url(self):
        url = re.sub(r'\W+', '', str(self.cleaned_data['title']))
        return url
```

How can I add `form.url` data to the form before saving?

Model:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Title"),
        max_length=60,
        unique=True,
        blank=False)
    receiver = models.ManyToManyField(
        EmployeeType,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Employee Type',
        related_name='quiz_receiver')
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("Description"),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_("A description of the quiz"))
    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_("e.g. 'blackjackshuffling'"),
        verbose_name=_("User friendly URL"))
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant model? Normally this is done with `slugify`, and at the *model* layer.

Comment: Edited the post. Should I be overriding the save method in the Model? For some reason I was thinking I should be creating the field closer to the view.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

Comment: Oh very nice! I will use that and override the model save method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SlugField` is often not specified in a `ModelForm`, but constructed by the model. One can make use of the [**`slugify`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) for that:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    # …
    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60,
        blank=False,
        editable=True,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_("e.g. 'blackjackshuffling'"),
        verbose_name=_('User friendly URL')
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            base_url = url = slugify(self.title)
            i = 0
            while self._meta.model.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
                url = f'{base_url}{i}'
                i += 1
            self.url = url
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Perhaps it is however more convenient to use the [**`AutoSlugField`** [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) from the [**`django-autoslug`** package [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can install this in your virtual environment with:

```
pip3 install django-autoslug
```

In your model you can then specify from what field it should populate and let the `AutoSlugField` handle the rest of the logic:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Quiz(models.Model):
    # …
    url = AutoSlugField(
        populate_from='title',
        unique=True
    )
```

Comment: Is the `while` loop simply making sure there are not two of the same urls?

Comment: @DavidAlford: exactly, it thus checks if there is already an object with the given slug.

Comment: I have a question about this code. I notice that you are calling `super().save()`  *after* the code but many methods call this before - what is the difference/uses?

Comment: @DavidAlford: that your first set the slug, before saving the object to the database. if you would do it afterwards, you would need to save it again, to update the record at the database side.